# paperclip saving files but not reading them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, attachment

I'm working on a project that requires attachments. Specifically, I need to attach pictures to a product model.

That said, I followed a railscast (link [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip)) and I followed most of the instructions (as some I think are outdated). I ended up with the following:

In the  products **form**:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Pic"%><br />
    <%= f.file_field :pic %>
  </div>
```

In the products **model**:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :brand_id, :name, :pic

  attr_accessor :pic_file_name
  attr_accessor :pic_content_type
  attr_accessor :pic_file_size
  attr_accessor :pic_updated_at

  has_attached_file :pic
```

And to see the resulting attachment, in the products **show** view:

```
<p>
  <b>Pic:</b>
  <%= image_tag @product.pic.url %>
</p>
```

Now, the thing is that even though the log shows that the image selected with the `file_field` was uploaded successfully:

```
Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-22 17:10:56 -0500
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"llIJTXKH87e7vpjX1A7Kmcz6BD2UToPvIfVd1bqmA58=", "product"=>{"brand_id"=>"1", "name"=>"asda\
sdsa", "pic"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9cfdb201c8 @original_filename="3.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Conten\
t-Disposition: form-data; name=\"product[pic]\"; filename=\"3.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/_r/d96rh\
0652xndcknb2txzn77r0000gn/T/RackMultipart20130422-2306-qoojw2>>}, "commit"=>"Create Product"}
  ^[[1m^[[36m (0.1ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mbegin transaction^[[0m
  ^[[1m^[[35mSQL (76.1ms)^[[0m  INSERT INTO "products" ("brand_id", "created_at", "image_content_type", "image_file_name", "image_file_size"\
, "image_updated_at", "name", "pic_content_type", "pic_file_name", "pic_file_size", "pic_updated_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?\
, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["brand_id", 1], ["created_at", Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:10:56 UTC +00:00], ["image_content_type", nil], ["image_file_name"\
, nil], ["image_file_size", nil], ["image_updated_at", nil], ["name", "asdasdsa"], ["pic_content_type", nil], ["pic_file_name", nil], ["pic_\
file_size", nil], ["pic_updated_at", nil], ["updated_at", Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:10:56 UTC +00:00]]
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  ^[[1m^[[36m (0.9ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mcommit transaction^[[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/10
Completed 302 Found in 126ms (ActiveRecord: 77.1ms)
```

I never actually get to see the image, as it always says "Missing".

Now, looking into the public/system dir, I can see the model directory there, as well as the Paperclip storage dir tree, as well as the image I tried to save:

```
$ ls public/system/products/pics/000/000/010/original/
3.JPG
```

I did set the ImageMagick path, in file

> config/initializers/paperclip.rb

Which holds:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/Users/<my_user>/Documents/non-ios_apps/ImageMagick-6.8.1/bin/"
```

So there, I've no idea why the images *are* being uploaded, but cannot be read. Which may well have to do with it not saving anything into the database, so far as attachements are concerned, but I'm not sure if they are separate issues or one triggers the other.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Using:
Rails 3.2.10
"paperclip", "~> 3.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file is being uploaded with the post request, but if you look in the SQL the script is running, all the pic attributes are being set to nil.

I'm not sure where the attr_accessor lines in your model came from, as I don't see them mentioned in the railscast or on the current paperclip docs. These may be what is causing your problem.

The railscast is five years old, so I would suggest going to the paperclip project on github at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip, and reading how to install and use the current version of paperclip. They have a very simple walkthrough on getting it up and running.

Comment: Thanks! I had added all the attr_accessor due to an error while setting things up, something about mass assignment I had run into in the past, and I figured I needed to add those if the paperclip migration was incomplete or something like that.